# expected method to write dictionary element not found on object of type "NSDictionary *"

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
+ (NSDateFormatter *) formatter : (NSString *) format  : (NSTimeZone*) timeZone  : (NSLocale *) locale {
    format = DefaultFormat;
    timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
    locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
    NSString *hashKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu%lu%lu", (unsigned long)format.hash, (unsigned long)timeZone.hash, (unsigned long)locale.hash];
    NSDictionary *formatters = [NSDate sharedDateFormatters];
    NSDateFormatter *cachedDateFormatter = formatters[hashKey];
    if (cachedDateFormatter != nil) {
        return cachedDateFormatter;
    }
    else {
        NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
        formatter.dateFormat = format;
        formatter.timeZone = timeZone;
        formatter.locale = locale;
        formatters[hashKey] = formatter;
        return formatter;
    }

}
```

The error appears on this line:     `formatters[hashKey] = formatter;`

The error: expected method to write dictionary element not found on object of type "NSDictionary *"

More context:

```
+ (NSMutableDictionary<NSString *, NSDateFormatter *>*)sharedDateFormatters {
    static NSMutableDictionary *dict = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        dict = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    });
    return dict;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot update an `NSDictionary` object as it's immutable.

**EDIT** Since showing where `sharedDateFormatters` comes from:

You simply have to make `formatters` an `NSMutableDictionary` instead of an `NSDictionary`, as that's what the class method returns, and then the code will work correctly:

```
NSMutableDictionary *formatters = [NSDate sharedDateFormatters];
```

Comment: What would you advise then ? I am converting a swift library into Objective-C.

Comment: You need to start by telling us where `sharedDateFormatters` comes from, as it's not part of the standard `NSDate` class.

Comment: Gave +1 to your answer :)

Comment: I've already done likewise to your question, for the simple reason you made it possible to answer; not all questions are possible to answer.